# Pex error during the team build ( TFS 2010 Build )

Tags: crash, tfsbuild, pex

We have been using pex and moles for unitest with TFS2010. Lately the pex and moles started to crash randomly during the test run. We couldn't reproduce this error on developer machine. Crash only happen on Team build servers. We are using version en_visual_studio_2010_pex_0.94.51006.1_power_tools_x86_exe_593303

Here is the error from build log.

```
Test Run Error.
Passed  270

Total   270
Results file:  C:\Builds\8\Release-1\Dev_DotNetFramework_Integration\TestResults\XXX_XXX_2011-11-23 02_11_07_Any CPU_Debug.trx
Test Settings: XXXX

Run has the following issue(s):
[host] An unhandled exception System.NullReferenceException occured while executing the unit tests
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
at System.Messaging.MessageEnumerator.Close()
at System.Messaging.MessageEnumerator.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
at System.Messaging.MessageEnumerator.Finalize()
[agent] host process exited with exit code 255 - 0xff. See http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/redmond/projects/pex/wiki/Exit Codes for more information.
```

Here are  event logs from build server

1)

```
Application: Microsoft.Moles.VsHost.x86.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.NullReferenceException
Stack:
   at System.Messaging.MessageEnumerator.Close()
   at System.Messaging.MessageEnumerator.Dispose(Boolean)
   at System.Messaging.MessageEnumerator.Finalize()
```

2)

```
Faulting application name: Microsoft.Moles.VsHost.x86.exe, version: 0.94.51006.1, time stamp: 0x4cacdf4d
Faulting module name: unknown, version: 0.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x00000000
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x12f17f38
Faulting process id: 0x3768
Faulting application start time: 0x01cca9af1bf4bcf3
Faulting application path: c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\Microsoft.Moles.VsHost.x86.exe
Faulting module path: unknown
Report Id: 85a87b73-15a2-11e1-a29e-78e7d1906fee
```

Comment: Have you seen http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vststest/thread/5732684c-94b3-436c-b1d8-41b7ec8d47dd ?